# How to return the ASCII string after a given string of numbers?

Tags: python, loops, arraylist, ascii, reverse

in order to print the ASCII I need to reverse the string so that what I've done and then to take for example 41 11 etc. and convert it to char. The outcome should be a word(in this case, Hacker)

The conversion need to be according to this:
1.the value range from A to Z is from 65 to 90
2.the value range from a to z is from 97 to 122
3.the value of the space character is 32

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

### that's what I get currently:
I get Unicode characters

['41', '11', '01', '10', '17', '99', '99', '27']
41 11 01 10 17 99 99 27
)
cc

---

```
s="729799107101114"

rs=s[::-1]

import re
new=re.findall('..',rs)
print(new)
n=""
for num in new:
    n+=num+" "
print(n)

j=''.join(chr(int(i)) for i in n.split())
print(j)
```

Comment: is `s` hex? I.e. does "77" stand for "w" or "M"?

Comment: 77 needs to be M. I've added the ranges

Comment: Is there any chance you have an excess '9' in the example string?

Comment: yes sorry I fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input presented numbers on `ASCII` codes. i.e `72` is the `H` char.

Then the outcome is look like this:

```
s="72 97 99 107 101 114"
j=''.join(chr(int(i)) for i in s.split())
print(j)
```

[**Output**]

```
Hacker
```

[**EDIT**]:

In this part, we'll tokenize the numbers as it, without space.

```
s="721111193211611132114101116117114110321161041013265836773733211511611410511010332971021161011143297321031051181011103211511611410511010332111102321101171099810111411563"
j=''
start=0
step=2
while start < len(s)-1:
    n=s[start:start+2]
    if 32<=int(n)<=99:
        start+=2
    if int(n)<32:
        n=s[start:start+3]
        start+=3        
    j=j+(chr(int(n)))
print(j)
```

[**Output2**:] In this sequence numbers sample we'll get this sentence:

```
How to return the ASCII string after a given string of numbers?
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've thought it will be harder, but I need to add spaces to the string also and I need to reverse the string first

Comment: @Bordento22, Look to the edit Update. Now, we did not need to add spaces manually to the string.

Comment: Can you explain why till 99? why not till 96 for example?

Comment: It's all about [*tens and hundreds place*]. So, **99** is the biggest number that can contain "**2 digits**". Whereas, we take **32** as the smallest with "**2 digits**". In another hand, the numbers that contain "**3 digits**" are starting from **100** to **122** in our case. Hope this is clear for you now, @Bordento22.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less verbose version:

```
res = ''
start = end = 0
while end < len(s):
    end = start + 2 + (s[start] == '1')
    res += chr(int(s[start:end]))
    start = end
```